# odd behavior with Zend2/doctrine pagination when displaying the DB records in my view file

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using the doctrine provided DoctrinePaginator (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Paginator/Adapter/DoctrinePaginator.php)

But I'm encountering very very odd behavior.

This is a screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePL1F.jpg) of my SQL ran using SQL Developer (running oracle 11g here). This is basically what doctrine is running. As you can see at record 100 is a person with the lastname "Allen". The odd behavior happens when I try to display the records in my view file.

This 2nd screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0X53.jpg) was made with $recordsPerPage set to 100 (see controller code below). The top of the image would tell you the SQL used ($queryBuilder->getDql()). As you can see from the image, the last person in the page is a person with the lastname "Azamov". According to the SQL I ran in SQL developer, the person in record 100 should have been a person with the lastname "Allen.

You can also see the number 100 below "Azamov". This was calculated by initializing a variable called $tempCounter in my view page and then incrementing it using ++$tempCounter. (view code at the end)

The 290 number you see near the top of the image is from $adapter->count() (also found in the controller code below).

This 3rd screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWG1N.jpg) was made with $recordPerPage set to 200. Again, "Azamov" was the last person.

It seems to me that somehow, the records displayed are not following whatever order I set in my SQL.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks

---

**this is my controller code**

```
public function searchAction() {
    $recordsPerPage = 100;

    if ($this->request->isGet()) {
        $form = new DirectorySearchForm();
        $directory = new DirectoryModel();

        $form->setInputFilter($directory->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($this->request->getQuery());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $directoryDao = new DirectoryDao();

            $directory->populate($form->getData());
            $adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($directoryDao->searchStaffDirectory($this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder(), $directory)));

            $paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($recordsPerPage);
            $page = (int)$this->params()->fromQuery("page");
            $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

            //var_dump();
            return array(
                    "staffList" => $paginator,
                    "recordCount" => $adapter->count(),
                    "recordsPerPage" => $recordsPerPage,
            );
        }
    }
    return $this->viewModel;
}
```

**my view code**

```
<?php

//  Declare temporary variables here
$oddEven = array('odd', 'even');
$tempCounter = 0;

?>

Found <?php echo $recordCount; ?> records<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><a style="text-decoration: none" title="Many different prefixes apply to campus extensions. Click on name or phone number for contact details."><h2>Click on name or  phone number for contact details</h2></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="searchResults highlightOrgStructure">name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="searchResults highlightOrgStructure">Telephone</th>
        <th scope="col" class="searchResults highlightOrgStructure">Position</th>
        <th scope="col" class="searchResults highlightOrgStructure">Department</th>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).tooltip({
                content: function () {
                    return $(this).prop('title');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php foreach($staffList as $staff) { ?>
        <?php ++$tempCounter; ?>

        <tr class="<?php echo $oddEven[$tempCounter % 2]; ?>">
            <td class="searchResults"><?php echo $staff->surname; if (strlen($staff->firstname) > 0) { echo ", ". $staff->firstname . " " . $staff->title; } ?></td>
            <td class="searchResults"><?php echo $staff->telephoneNumber; ?></td>
            <td class="searchResults"><?php echo $staff->role; ?></td>
            <td class="searchResults"><?php echo $staff->department; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php echo $tempCounter."<hr>"; ?>
```